# How to make a cuboid's one particular corner point be always at (0, 0, 0) regardless of its scale in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, the cuboid is formed with 6 different planes. I might switch later to using cubes instead of planes but that's beside the point.

I will need to frequently change the dimensions of this cuboid because it's supposed to be a model for different rooms (I don't know the exact dimensions for the rooms yet).

I need to choose a certain corner point to be exactly at (0, 0, 0) point in space and I want to rely on this fact that that certain point is always at (0, 0, 0) but moving the whole cuboid manually so that the corner point is at (0, 0, 0) is not an elegant or effective way of doing it. Is there any simple way that I'm missing?

I'm sure there is and I'm missing it because I'm fairly new at Unity. Maybe a simple script with ExecuteInEditMode attribute? Or maybe if I organize the hierarchy in a certain way, it'll happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your cuboid a default dimension (e.g. 1,1,1) and make it child of new empty GameObject which is at position (0,0,0) and has the default dimension (1,1,1). Move the cuboid until the corner is on (0,0,0).

In this example would be e.g. something like (0.5,0.5,0.5).

Than in the future don't scale the cuboid but scale the parent object instead -> corner aways stays at (0,0,0).

Comment: Thanks! Silly me, I actually tried that but was too lazy to move the GameObject exactly on the corner and when changing scale to a large value it became far more apparent and I just thought it didn't work.